# C# Cache Saxon Compiler and Executable objects

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, saxon

Using below code to run Evaluations using SaxonCA API

```
Task newTask = Task.Run(() =>
{
    Processor processor = new Processor();
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = processor.NewDocumentBuilder();
    documentBuilder.IsLineNumbering = true;
    documentBuilder.WhitespacePolicy = WhitespacePolicy.PreserveAll;
    XQueryCompiler compiler = processor.NewXQueryCompiler();
    string query = BuildXqueryString();

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
    {
        XQueryExecutable executable = compiler.Compile(query);
        XQueryEvaluator evaluator = executable.Load();
        evaluator.ContextItem = documentBuilder.Build(xmlNode);
        var evaluations = evaluator.Evaluate();
    }
}
```

Queries (Xquery) are constant and never change until there is new build. Above code is run parallel for different documents. Wanted to check if there is any way to Cache the compiler/evaluator object to avoid query compilations for every document we process.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `XQueryExecutable` is *immutable* and *thread-safe*, so you can safely cache it: for example by keeping a (thread-safe) map or hash table from the query string to the `XQueryExecutable`. The only caveat is that you will have to change the way you instantiate the Processor object: rather than creating a new Processor every time you run a query, you should have a single Processor object for the entire application, because the compiled query and the source document must be built under the control of the same Processor.

The `XQueryCompiler` is serially re-usable, but since the `ErrorList` object is updated during the course of a compilation, it shouldn't be used in more than one thread concurrently. So you may find it simplest to create a new `XQueryCompiler` every time you compile a query.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Will try to change the application to use a single Processor and Cache XQueryExecutable.

Comment: After creating One Process for the App and Caching XQueryExecutable, the application is working and got improvement in the performance. Thank you

Comment: Good. Please click the tick-mark to mark the answer as accepted, this helps other readers who come to this later.